# How to check if an Integer variable of @RequestParam type in Spring is "empty"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, object

If I have a code in which:

```
@RequestParam(value = "amount", required = false) Integer amount
```

is one of my parameters, what can I do to prevent the user from assigning an "empty" value to this parameter?

For example: let's suppose they requested, on Postman, the URL **http://localhost:8080/myproject?amount=** exactly like this, without assigning a value to this parameter. How can I validate it in my code and prevent them from assigning an empty value to an Integer object?
I mean, *required* really has to be defined as *false* - since it is not necessary for this parameter to be informed - but, if it is informed, it can't receive an empty value.
If this parameter was an object of String type, I know I could just write a simple

```
if (amount.isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

but since it is of Integer type I don't know how to validate it, because the variable is not null (since it was informed on the URL), although no value will have been assigned.

In short: I want these to be allowed on URL call:

http://localhost:8080/myproject

http://localhost:8080/myproject?amount=2222

But not this:

http://localhost:8080/myproject?amount=

Comment: Spring MVC should fail to convert the query parameter and throw an exception, and probably return a 400 back to the client. Have you tried hitting that _bad_ URL? What happened?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/myproject?amount` will set amount = null i think. Or it does in my project.

Comment: @Savior it does nothing. Spring shows no error.

Comment: And what's the value of `amount`?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in that controller method and seeing what happens in the debugger? That's the best way of identifying how it actually parses these various inputs.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas So, how can I tell Java/Spring that this null:

    http://localhost:8080/myProject?amount

is different from this one:

    http://localhost:8080/myproject

Comment: @Savior the value of amount when I declare it as Integer and call it is null, but when I declare amount as String and call it, its value is just empty (but not null). Is there a way to do the same with an Integer attribute?

Comment: Does it matter? In either case your not-required value is null/empty/not used. Are you trying to explicitly return a HTTP 400 response something?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes. And I have no idea about how to do it other than converting the Integer values to String. It would work, although it would become a shitty code.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to disable/modify the [type conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion) that Spring does on the query parameters. You can customize the converter to not accept non-numeric inputs at all and instead throw an exception which would result in a returned HTTP 400 response.

Answer (score 0):

If amount is not passed in url `http://localhost:8080/myproject?amount=`, the by default `amount` value will be null, as Integer can contain null value

```
 @RequestMapping("/create3")
    public String create3(@RequestParam Integer amount){
        if(amount == null){
         //return bad request
        }
        System.out.println("amount: "+amount);
        return "Done";
    }
```